# Oracle 10g: Connect by prior

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

What is the difference between using `PRIOR` in

```
CONNECT BY  CUST_ID=  PRIOR  CUST_CUST_ID
```

and

```
CONNECT BY  PRIOR CUST_ID=   CUST_CUST_ID
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Prior defines parent row.

In your case:
CONNECT BY PRIOR CUST_ID = CUST_CUST_ID search for the next row (parent) where cust_id is equals to cust_cust_id from the current row.

CONNECT BY CUST_ID = PRIOR CUST_CUST_ID search for the next row (parent) where cust_cust_id is equals to cust_id from the current row.